# Rails query to find 2nd highest salary in employee table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an employee model and there will be certain records in the employees table with salary column. I need to find the record of second largest employee's salary 
How can i do it with a simple rails query??

Answer (score 8):

```
Employee.order(salary: :desc).offset(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

There could be better way, but I guess this works

```
Employee.order("salary DESC").limit(2).last
```

Comment: The employees table salary column  can contain same values also right.. So in that case this would return wrong results if the limit(2) has same values